# What does Meta stand for in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: metadata

What does the term "Meta" stand for in reference to Meta Data within SharePoint 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta-Data:-  It means data about data. Or more precisely more information about some 'information '.

In context of SharePoint (whether it's 2013) , in general it is information attached to elements. The different type of values entered for an element in a list or library. First we have columns and values present under the columns is known as "Metadata".

For example:

Say a document with name "HrLeavePolicy" is saved with column values such as

Column1 : **Purpose**

Value   :  "Leave"

and

Column2 : **Department**

Value   :  "IT"

Now document "**HrLeavePolicy**" is tagged with metadata '**Leave**' and '**IT**'.

This metdata is very useful as later users can possibly search the document using metadata '**Leave**' and '**IT**'.

Comment: You are Welcome. Happy to help you :)

Comment: Awesome explanation!